# JavaScript to Login to Website through Windows 8.1 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I developed a rudamentry powershell script that uses "$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application" to login to a website and retrieve some data.

I am trying to accomplish the same with a Windows 8.1 app - and cannot find much clear guidance in doing this.

I got as far as writing this form:

```
<form name="form1" action="https://URL.com" method="post">
            <h2>User Name:<input name="Username" type="text" /></h2>
            <h2>Password:<input name="Password" type="password" /></h2>
            <h2><input name="Button" type="submit" value="Log In" /></h2>
</form>
```

But this just opens IE at the specified url, and doesnt do anything else.

I want to be able to login to the website in the background without ie opening, grab the information and display in the windows app. I am having trouble finding a solution. I thought maybe JavaScript - but couldnt find something simple for my needs and I'm only new to this.

Comment: I think you may find the [Selenium PowerShell eXtensions](http://sepsx.codeplex.com/) helpful.